# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>' - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I've this kind of data as shown in the screenshot.

I want to fetch all the feild data of document including a field named `restHeaderBanner` of type `List<Map<String, dynamic>>>`.
All others feild data is being fetched as expected but only data of feild `restHeaderBanner` of type `List<Map<String, dynamic>>>` is showing null even though there is data in it as shown in the screenshot

I'm getting below output and error while fetching data.`restHeaderBanner` is null. Idk why.

```dart
I/flutter (22423): /n restNews : ============ {imageURL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/storeifie-e72e3.appspot.com/o/productPics%2Fimage_cropper_1627649118842.png%7D?alt=media&token=b8306f23-2e33-4f8f-8aad-8da5a47aef1f, description: new desctiption, title: new title}
I/flutter (22423): /n restHeaderBanner : ============ null
I/flutter (22423): /n mainPageHeader : ============ [Amazing food just few clicks away, Order from your fav restaurants now]

════════ Exception caught by provider ══════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown:
An exception was throw by _MapStream<DocumentSnapshot, RestaurantEssential> listened by

StreamProvider<RestaurantEssential>, but no `catchError` was provided.

Exception:
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>'

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I've `mainDataProvider` class in which there are all the providers that fetch data from database.

```dart
class MainDataProvider extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainDataProviderState createState() => _MainDataProviderState();
}

class _MainDataProviderState extends State<MainDataProvider> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   StreamProvider restaurantEssentialProvider = StreamProvider<RestaurantEssential>.value(
        value:  getrestaurantessentialsData,
        initialData: null,
      );    
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
    ...
     restaurantEssentialProvider,
    ...
    ],
    child: HomeView();
                   }
           }
```

```dart
class DatabaseService {

  Stream<RestaurantEssential> get getrestaurantessentialsData {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('restaurantEssentials')
        .doc('restaurantEssentials')
        .snapshots()
        .map(_restaurantessentialsDataFromSnapshot);
  }

   RestaurantEssential _restaurantessentialsDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot ) {

    try {
      print("/n restNews : ============ " +
          snapshot.data()['mainPageHeader'].toString());
      print("/n restHeaderBanner : ============ " +
          snapshot.data()['restHeaderBanner'].toString());
      print("/n mainPageHeader : ============ " +
          snapshot.data()['restNews'].toString());
    } catch (e) {
      print(
          "Exception inside database _restaurantessentialsDataFromSnapshot: " +
              e.toString());
    }

    return RestaurantEssential(
      mainPageHeader: snapshot.data()['mainPageHeader'] ?? {},
      restHeaderBanner: Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.data()) ?? [],
      restNews: snapshot.data()['restNews'] ?? [],
    );
  }
}

class RestaurantEssential {
  List<String> restNews;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> restHeaderBanner;
  Map<String, String> mainPageHeader;

  RestaurantEssential({
    this.restNews,
    this.restHeaderBanner,
    this.mainPageHeader,
  });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with `mainPageHeader` of `RestaurantEssential`, it is of type `Map<String, String>` and it is assigned with `_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>`.
Thats what the error says:

> type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>'

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with the code:

- `snapshot.data()['mainPageHeader']` returns `_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>` but you're assigning it to a parameter of type `Map<String, String>`
- `snapshot.data()['restHeaderBanner']` returns a `List` but you're trying to cast it to a `Map<String, dynamic>` and pass it to a parameter of type `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`
- `snapshot.data()['restNews]` returns a `List<dynamic>` but you're assigning to a parameter of type `List<String>`

### Solution:

You need to explicitly cast the types.

Update this block of code:

```dart
    return RestaurantEssential(
      mainPageHeader: snapshot.data()['mainPageHeader'] ?? {},
      restHeaderBanner: Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.data()) ?? [],
      restNews: snapshot.data()['restNews'] ?? [],
    );
```

to this:

```dart
   final Map<String, dynamic> data =
       Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.data());

   final Map<String, String> mainPageHeader =
       Map<String, String>.from(data['mainPageHeader']);

   final List<Map<String, dynamic>> restHeaderBanner =
       List.from(data['restHeaderBanner'])
           .map((e) => Map<String, dynamic>.from(e))
           .toList();

   final List<String> restNews =
       List.from(data['restNews']).map((e) => e as String).toList();

   return RestaurantEssential(
     mainPageHeader: mainPageHeader ?? {},
     restHeaderBanner: restHeaderBanner ?? [],
     restNews: restNews ?? [],
   );
```